Proper way to re-load data from S3 into lambda memory daily?
I'm new to the lifecycle of Lambda functions, so forgive my ignorance in advance!
I have an EventBridge schedule that calls a Lambda function daily at 3 am PST - this lambda function downloads some external files and stores them in S3. We'll call this Lambda-A.
I then have a lambda function that is called every few seconds by thousands of clients. This lambda function uses the data that's fetched daily by Lambda-A. So, I need to have this Lambda function (we'll call it Lambda-B) update its internal data to the fresh new data downloaded by Lambda-A.
My understanding of the Lambda lifecycle is that when a function is initially invoked, it will run its initialization (whatever is outside of the lambda_handler method) and then process the event through the handler. Once the event is processed, this lambda instance stays alive, handling subsequent requests, unless there are no requests for a while, at which point it shuts down. The exact period of inactivity that it takes to shut down, from what I understand, varies.
Ideally, I just want to have the aforementioned data in the static memory of Lambda-B, which is to say, I want to load it during the initialization and then keep using it in the handler. But if the lambda is called every few seconds, I imagine it will never shut down and get the chance to re-initialize, thus will never be able to pull the new data.
What's the best way to handle this? I was thinking Lambda-A could "shut down" Lambda-B after it downloaded the new data, this way on the next call to Lambda-B, a new instance would spin up, re-initialize, pull the new data, and all is well. After some research, I can't tell if it's possible to shut down a lambda instance this way.
Appreciate any recommendations!

Rather than attempt to make A control the lifecycle of B, B could just call HeadObject on the S3 object on each call, and reload it if it has a newer LastModified than last time it saw it.  (Also note that a Lambda Execution Environment has a max lifespan.  Currently it appears to be around 2 hours)

This is likely what you're after: How could I fully restart a lambda function runtime without having to make a new deployment?
If you use an environment variable and update it (could just be updating it with the current time), it will cause the runtime to be updated and the lambda execution environment to restart.
